# MongoDB query filter is being executed as update

Tags: mongodb

**EDITED.** More clarifications:

I use MongoDB 3.4 via Java Async Driver
This is one of my collection indexes:

```
posts:{orders.postReqID:1, unique:1}
```

For days I had an abnormal problem and that was I was facing such a record in my database:

```
posts:
{
    ...,
    orders
    [
        ...,
        {
            // Please notice there is an implicit postReqID:null
            viewCount: -1,
            amount: 1
        }
    ]
}, ...
```

I didn't know the cause, and I deleted such a sub document several times.
Then I put a document with `orders.postReqID:null` to diagnose the problem(Because I had a unique index which wouldn't let to put more null values for this field):

```
{ //This is the document I inserted inside my db
    ...
    orders:
    [
        {
        postReqID:Null
        date:0
        viewCount:0
        remaining:0
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the query that I was suspect of:

```
posts.findOneAndUpdate(
            and(new Document("visits.userID", userID),
                new Document("orders.postReqID", postReqID)
                ),
            new Document("$inc",
                               new Document("orders.$.viewCount", 1)
                               .append("orders.$.remaining", -1)
                        )
                        .append("$set", new Document("orders.$.endDate", currentTime)
                                        .append("visits.$.date", currentTime)),
                            (r, t) ->
                            {
                                if (t != null)
                                {
                                    t.fillInStackTrace();
                                    t.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        )
```

And I encounter such an error (after putting that document inside my db and executing this query again):

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 11000: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: ViewMember.posts index: orders.postReqID_1 dup key: { : null }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: ViewMember.posts index: orders.postReqID_1 dup key: { : null }", "code" : 11000, "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
at com.sunova.bot.MongoDBDriver$14.lambda$requestAsync$1(MongoDBDriver.java:768)
at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl$2$2.onResult(MongoClientImpl.java:144)
at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$ReferenceCountedReleasingWrappedCallback.onResult(OperationHelper.java:368)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper$1.onResult(CommandOperationHelper.java:381)
at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$1.onResult(DefaultServer.java:185)
at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol$CommandResultCallback.callCallback(CommandProtocol.java:275)
at com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:48)
at com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:23)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$2.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:470)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$2.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:464)
at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$3.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:119)
at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$3.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:115)
at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.executeCallbackAndReceiveResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:378)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1700(InternalStreamConnection.java:66)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseBuffersCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:420)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseBuffersCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:389)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback.onSuccess(InternalStreamConnection.java:562)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback.access$2200(InternalStreamConnection.java:517)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback$ResponseBodyCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:584)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback$ResponseBodyCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:568)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:447)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:444)
at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:218)
at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:201)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This exception means there is an abnormal update done by this query, which this query shouldn't do. This query should not insert any new sub-array element in `orders` sub-document, but it does. What causes this to be so? If you look at first document (at the beginning of this question) you see that there happens two increments in `viewCount` and `amount` and it should be done, but the insertion which is done in `orders` by this query is not intended as you see. Seems MongoDB doesn't update the sub-array element that I intended, and puts new element there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  use of `$positional` operator is conflicting.

You have two array indexes in play `visits` and `orders`. Based on the order of evaluation of `$and`, it will resolve it to one index value.

Looks like in your case the positional operator is resolving to index value of `visits.userID` for the criteria you provided.

Now update will use the index which may not have a matching `orders` and it creates a new entry for `order` using the query fields and update fields you provided.

Comment: So do you mean that I can't search inside two array field of my document, in one query? Can you tell me what else I can do about it? How can I change my query in order to solve this?

Comment: I mean not using positional operator. You just have to update one array at a time with the appropriate index found from query part.

Comment: Seems legit. Thanks for your response :) I will change my code and mark your answer as accepted after doing so.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have a user with a null field value. You just find and remove the null document and it would work. This problem generally comes with if a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique index, the index will store a null value for this document.

If you fix the error and you want to use multiple documents with null values, you can use sparse index. Here is an explanation about sparse:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/

Comment: Thanks for your response, as I said I myself put a null field value in order to diagnose why this happens. Please look at query. It doesn't involve any document insertion, that means there shouldn't exist any inserted `orders.postReqID` values, then why I get a duplicate key error?

Comment: as i said did you tried sparse index instead of unique in your collection indexes? if i understand your problem it should be related with indexes.

Comment: Dude I don't need null values in my indexed field, all I try to say is this query puts some sub document with `postReqID` of null, which it shouldn't do. I observed my db for several days and understood that this query is culprit. This is for example one of insertions by this query: `orders: [... , {postReqID: null, remaining: -1, viewCount:1}]`. You see while this query is not supposed to do such an update, it does!